# Codecoverage phpunit test issue

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I am running phpunit version 9.2 and I would like to know why my method is not covered in the phpunit coverage.

This is my class:

```
class Methods extends Template
{

    const DISABLED_PAYMENT_METHODS_1 = 'free';
    const DISABLED_PAYMENT_METHODS_2 = 'adyen_cc';
    const DISABLED_PAYMENT_METHODS_3 = 'adyen_oneclick';

    protected $paymentMethodList;

    protected $storeManager;

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PaymentMethodList $paymentMethodList,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->paymentMethodList = $paymentMethodList;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getPaymentMethods()
    {
        try {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $paymentList = $this->paymentMethodList->getActiveList($storeId);
            $resultPayments = [];

            foreach ($paymentList as $payment) {
                if ($payment->getCode() !== self::DISABLED_PAYMENT_METHODS_1 &&
                    $payment->getCode() !== self::DISABLED_PAYMENT_METHODS_2 &&
                    $payment->getCode() !== self::DISABLED_PAYMENT_METHODS_3
                ) {
                    $resultPayments[] = $payment;
                }
            }

            return $resultPayments;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my test class:

```
class MethodsTest extends TestCase
{

    private $model;


    private function getSimpleMock($originalClassName)
    {
        return $this->getMockBuilder($originalClassName)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
    }

    public function setUp() : void
    {
        $context = $this->getSimpleMock(Context::class);
        $paymentMethodList = $this->getSimpleMock(PaymentMethodList::class);
        $storeManager = $this->getSimpleMock(StoreManagerInterface::class);
        $logger = $this->getSimpleMock(LoggerInterface::class);

        $this->model = new Methods(
            $context,
            $paymentMethodList,
            $storeManager,
            $logger,
            []
        );
    }

    public function testGetPaymentMethods()
    {
        $stub = $this->createMock(Methods::class);
        $stub->method('getPaymentMethods')
            ->willReturn([]);
        try {
            $stub->getPaymentMethods();
            $this->fail("Expected exception!");
        } catch (\Exception $error) {
            $this->assertEquals("Expected exception!", $error->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the command to get the coverage. I am getting:
[image]

I am really curious why my test is not covered or at least the exception part ? Would you please share you ideas why ? and what can i do in order to fix this ? Right now I got a 29 % and I would like to get at least 60% coverage.

Thank you

Comment: Your test method creates a mock for that method, so it's the mock method that is run.

Answer (score 1):

On this line `$stub = $this->createMock(Methods::class);` you are creating a mock of the `Methods` class, so not actually testing the real class.

You will need to use the object you created in your `setUp()` method, and set up mock returns on the dependencies you passed in (perhaps converting some of them to be class properties).

Comment: ok, but any clue how can i do this without using the mock ? it is also about dependency injection

Comment: Hi @Dezza, thnx for updating your post, but if you can get me a link or an example how can I do that , I would much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You should test the real class, as example:

```
public function testGetPaymentMethods()
{
    // define a payment
    $paymentFreeCode = $this->createMock(Payment::class);
    $paymentFreeCode->method('getcode')
        ->willReturn("free");

    // define a payment
    $payment = $this->createMock(Payment::class);
    $payment->method('getcode')
        ->willReturn("invalid-code");

    $paymentList = [
        $paymentFreeCode,
        $payment,
    ];

    // define a store
    $store = $this->createMock(Store::class);
    $store->method('getId')
        ->willReturn("my-store-id");

    // return store from the store manager
    $this->storeManager->method('getStore')
        ->willReturn(myStore);

    // return the payment list
    $this->paymentMethodList->method('getActiveList')->with("my-store-id")
        ->willReturn($paymentList);

    // call the real class instrumented with mocks
    $paymentMethods = $this->model->getPaymentMethods();

    $this->assertIsArray($paymentMethods);
    $this->assertCount($paymentMethods, 1);
}
```